# Problem with accessing AWS Route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have recently bought a domain (caracara.es) with Route 53. It seemed to register all good and AWS created a hosted zone automatically for it.

I wanted to link it to the web hosted on S3 and as per instructions I created an A record and selected a bucket Alias from the dropdown (its set as web bucket etc.). That is the result:

[image]

The issue I'm having is that I don't seem to be able to access my domain from the outside world (I waited about 12 hours now) and I'm not sure how can I debug what's wrong with it... (ping says unknown host)

BTW, I have NS records, SOA records automatically created by AWS.

Would appreciate any help,
Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Is your bucked called exactlly as your domain?

Comment: yes, it appeared on the list and all. That bit seems okay. I have a suspition that there's something up with the domain itself. But I'm not sure how does one investigate stuff like that

Comment: But why A record? Normally it is alias to s3.

Comment: It looks like you didn't purchase the domain through AWS? So you need to add the AWS nameservers in the hosted domain into your domains nameserver config.

Comment: I did get the domain via AWS. And they created hosted zone with NS automatically. Is there a way to check if those are correct?

Comment: what is error your are getting ? check policy of s3

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my domain was not setup correctly. The hosted zones NS automatically created by AWS didn't match the name server names of the domain itself.

Once I updated the domain to use nameservers from Hosted Zone - everything works fine.

Thanks for your help.
Michal